# How to handle unbalanced label data using FastText?

Tags: nlp, word2vec, fasttext

In FastText, I have unbalanced labels. What is the best way to handle it?

Comment: This blog https://machinelearningmastery.com/tactics-to-combat-imbalanced-classes-in-your-machine-learning-dataset/ gives some general answers can you add some details as to the domain specifics?

Comment: I dont see any satisfactory answer. is there a better resolution?

Answer (score 2):

Fasttext seems to handle unbalanced data pretty well. 
According to the [FAQ](https://fasttext.cc/docs/en/faqs.html)

> Note also that this loss is thought for classes that are unbalanced, that is some classes are more frequent than others.

Answer (score 1):

In our case here we have a very skewed dataset with **200+ classes** and **20%** of the classes containing **80% of all data**.

In our data, even with this highly skewed data, we have a **clear definition** of the texts inside our categories.

**Example**:
Text of the Majority Class: "*Hey, I need a **computer** and a **mouse** to open the **internet** and post a **programming** answer in **Stack** **Overflow***"

Text of the Minority Class: "*Hey, could please give me the following items: **Eggs**, **lettuce**, **onions**, **tomatoes**, **milk** and **wheat**?*"

As FastText deals with WordNGrams and hierarchical split if you have a **very well defined category** as my case above, the imbalance it's not a problem because of the nature of the algorithm.

Reference: [Bag of Tricks for Efficient Text Classification](https://arxiv.org/abs/1607.01759) - Armand Joulin, Edouard Grave, Piotr Bojanowski, Tomas Mikolov